# Spring @Resource not loading list of beans

Tags: java, spring

When I try to load a resource, it never gets loaded and instead comes back as `null`. My code is as follows:

**Controller.java**

```
@Controller
@Path("/users")
public class UsersAPI {
    @Resource(name = "dataLoaderList")
    private List<DataLoader> dataLoaderList;
}
```

**spring.xml**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.my.package" />

<import resource="classpath:spring/commons.xml" />
<import resource="spring-dataloader.xml" />
<import resource="spring-security.xml" />
```

**spring-dataloader.xml**

```
<bean id="dataLoaderList"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ListFactoryBean">
    <property name="sourceList">
        <list>
            <ref bean="dataLoader1" />
            <ref bean="dataLoader2" />
            <ref bean="dataLoader3" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

What could I be missing?

**EDIT:**
I tried loading the resource in a JUnit Test, and it worked. So I have no idea why it wouldn't work in my Controller.

**junit**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:spring/spring.xml")
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
public class Test {

   @Resource(name = "dataLoaderList")
   private List<DataLoader> dataLoaderList;

}
```

Comment: How did you load in JUnit?In what package is the controller? How is it called?

Comment: The controller is in `com.my.package.controller`. And the project is packaged into a `war` file and is used in a Tomcat server

Comment: Is profiling set properly for your development access?

Comment: Yes, it's set as an environment variable, and that resource is not profile dependent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change `@Controller` annotation to `@Component` and that fixed my error. I have no idea why it worked.